# How can i install MYSQL-python database in Django with virtualenv

Tags: python, mysql, django

When I am trying to install MYSQL-python to virtualenv in my linux , I am getting these types of errors.(fightvaw) is my virtualenv. I tyr pip install mysql-python command to install MYSQL-python inside virtualenv. Than,how can I connect this database with django?Some demo will help to start my project.

```
 (fightvaw)ramesh@ramesh-Compaq-Presario-CQ40-Notebook-PC /var/www/fightvaw $ pip install mysql-python
  Downloading/unpacking mysql-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB): 108kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/var/www/fightvaw/build/mysql-python/setup.py) egg_info for package mysql-python
  sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/var/www/fightvaw/build/mysql-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
  File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
  EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
  Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
  sh: 1: mysql_config: not found

  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/var/www/fightvaw/build/mysql-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>

  metadata, options = get_config()

 File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config

 libs = mysql_config("libs_r")

 File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config

 raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))

EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

----------------------------------------
  Cleaning up...
   Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in       /var/www/fightvaw/build/mysql-python
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ramesh/.pip/pip.log
(fightvaw)ramesh@ramesh-Compaq-Presario-CQ40-Notebook-PC /va
```

Comment: what os are you using? If linux try installing `libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: Don't put your code in `/var/www/`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install mysql itself first, before you can install the Python library.